# Bernoulli Sequence Lab

Tags: python, python-2.x, compression

I'm writing some Python 2 code with which to analyze the compressibility of random bitstrings. It's working pretty well right now, and now I'd like to request some help making sure it follows [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and is in other ways pythonic.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed Feb 21 14:34:38 2018
Takes bitstring, makes dictionary and both encodes and decodes by that
dictionary; also includes functions to help utilize that, including creating 
Bernoulli Sequences
Run to see demonstration
@author: Post169
"""


import numpy as np


def bern_seq(length,freq1s):
    """bern_seq creates Bernoulli sequence (random bitstring) of given length
    with given freq of 1s
    """
    bseq = tuple([int(np.random.rand(1) < freq1s) for _ in range(length)])
    return bseq


def dict_words(data_length):
    """dict_words finds max possible number of words in a dictionary built from
    bitstring of given length
    """
    from numpy import ceil
    max_length = 1.
    sum_lengths = 2.
    total_words = 2.
    while sum_lengths < data_length:
        max_length += 1
        sum_lengths = 2*(max_length*2**max_length - 2**max_length + 1)
    extra_length = sum_lengths - data_length
    total_words = 2**(max_length+1) - 2
    extra_words = ceil(extra_length/max_length)
    final_words = total_words - extra_words
    return int(final_words)


def data_size(dict_size):
    """data_size finds min bitstring length that could generate dictionary of
    given size
    """
    dict_len = 1
    data_len = 1
    while dict_len < dict_size:
        data_len += 1
        dict_len = dict_words(data_len)
    return data_len


def check_dict(data,dictionary,ii,build_dict = False):
    """check_dict searches given data string, starting at position ii, for 
    largest matching word in given dictionary; if build_dict, goes one char
    farther
    """
    """km is string length compared to dictionary, length is string length 
    checked for exceeding data length; only different if build_dict
    """
    km = 1
    length = 1
    """Look for the longest word in the dictionary that matches the data"""
    while data[ii:ii+km] in dictionary:
        km += 1
        length = km - 1 + int(build_dict)
        """What to do for the string that reaches the end of the data"""
        if build_dict & (ii+length > len(data)):
            return "", km
        elif (not build_dict) & (ii+length == len(data)):
            return data[ii:ii+length],km
    return data[ii:ii+length], length


def bin_words(length, howMany):
    """bin_words generates a sequence of bit strings of a certain length"""
    length = int(length)
    howMany = int(howMany)
    for ii in range(howMany):
        bin_string = bin(ii)[2:].zfill(length)
        yield tuple([int(x) for x in bin_string])


class LZ78Dict(object):

    def __init__(self,data):
        """Create LZ78Dict object by breaking the given data into a dictionary"""
        self._data30 = data[:30]
        data_length = len(data)
        dict_length_max = dict_words(data_length)
        self.keylength = int(np.ceil(np.log2(dict_length_max)))
        bitno = 0
        self.encode_dict = {}
        for ward in bin_words(self.keylength,dict_length_max):
            building = True
            next_w,bitstep = check_dict(data,self.encode_dict,bitno,building)
            if next_w == "":
                break
            bitno += bitstep
            self.encode_dict[next_w] = ward
        self.decode_dict = {v: k for k, v in self.encode_iter}

    def __len__(self):
        """Define __len__ as number of entries in the dictionary"""
        return len(self.decode_dict)

    def __repr__(self):
        """Give length of the dictionaries as the __repr__ and __str__"""
        return "LZ78Dict({self._data30[:-1]}...))".format(self=self)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Encode & decode dictionaries of "+str(len(self))+" entries each"

    @property
    def encode_iter(self):
        """Turn the encoding dictionary into encode_iter iterable property"""
        return self.encode_dict.iteritems()

    def encode(self,message):
        """encode method expresses given string in terms of encode dictionary"""
        ii = 0
        kryptos = ()
        while ii < len(message):
            not_building = False
            enc_dict = self.encode_dict
            ward,di = check_dict(message,enc_dict,ii,not_building)
            kryptos += self.encode_dict[ward]
            ii += di
        return kryptos

    def decode(self,coded):
        """decode method expresses given string in terms of decode dictionary"""
        ii = 0
        original = ()
        delta = self.keylength
        while ii < len(coded):
            ward = self.decode_dict[coded[ii:ii+delta]]
            original += ward
            ii += delta
        return original


"""Run module as command to see demonstration of functionalities"""
if __name__ == "__main__":
    max_key_len = 8
    print "Let's make a dictionary with ",max_key_len,"-bit keys out of a random bitstring"
    dict_len_max = 2**max_key_len
    print "How long should that bitstring be if we want max length but certainty of 8-bit keys?"
    dat_len = data_size(dict_len_max)
    print "It should be ",dat_len," bits long"
    freq1s = np.random.rand(1)
    print "Let's make it ",round(freq1s*100,1),"percent 1's"
    bitstring = bern_seq(dat_len,freq1s)
    print "The first 30 digits are ",bitstring[:30]
    print
    library = LZ78Dict(bitstring)
    dict1 = library.encode_dict
    print "This dictionary has ",len(dict1),"key-value pairs"
    coded1 = library.encode(bitstring)
    print "It was able to encode the bitstring in ",len(coded1)," bits"
    print "The first 30 of those are ",coded1[:30]
    print
    print "Now let's decode that"
    decoded1 = library.decode(coded1)
    print "The first 30 digits of the decoded bitstring are ",decoded1[:30]
    matches = decoded1 == bitstring
    print "It is ",matches," that these code operations are able to reverse each other flawlessly."
```

I have already noticed that, while the UTF-8 encoding used here is the PEP 8 way for Python 3, ASCII should be used instead for Python 2; I've put that on my to do list and am concerned about other parts.

Answer (score 2):

I'm just picking one early function to review.

> ```
> def dict_words(data_length):
>     """dict_words finds max possible number of words in a dictionary built from
>     bitstring of given length
>     """
> ```

What does that mean? Where should I look for an explanation of what it means to build a dictionary from a bitstring?

> ```
>     from numpy import ceil
> ```

My understanding is that importing with narrow scopes like this is discouraged.

> ```
>     max_length = 1.
>     sum_lengths = 2.
>     total_words = 2.
> ```

Why floating point? Both the names and the usage strongly suggest to me that the values will always be integers. If this is a hack to avoid using big integers, that should be documented.

> ```
>     while sum_lengths < data_length:
>         max_length += 1
>         sum_lengths = 2*(max_length*2**max_length - 2**max_length + 1)
> ```

Where did this formula come from, and what does it mean?

> ```
>     extra_length = sum_lengths - data_length
>     total_words = 2**(max_length+1) - 2
> ```

Ditto. Also, why use `2**(max_length+1)` here and `2*2**max_length` for `sum_lengths`?

> ```
>     extra_words = ceil(extra_length/max_length)
> ```

If working with integer values, this could be implemented as `extra_words = (extra_length + max_length - 1) // max_length`

> ```
>     final_words = total_words - extra_words
>     return int(final_words)
> ```

The addition of the name `final_words` doesn't communicate anything to me about what the difference means, so as far as I'm concerned this could be inlined. (Obviously, if following my suggestions above then the `int()` call could also be eliminated).

FWIW, after reading the code carefully I still have no idea what this function's purpose is.

Comment: On the floating point numbers - Python rounds the ratios of integers, so the definition of <pre>extra_words<code> gives a different value depending on whether the numbers are int or float, and I want it precise.

Comment: @Post169, keep reading...

Comment: On the purpose of this function, this is about a dictionary that is built, by the **Lempel-Ziv '78 algorithm**, from a bitstring.
On the formulas, I came up with them myself while deliberating on this purpose.
I think the two equivalent expressions are each ideal for the contexts they are in.
Excellent, now I have no need of floating point numbers!
So, `return total_words - extra_words`?

Comment: I changed `total_words` to `2*(2**max_length - 1)`

Answer (score 2):

A small comment: there are lots of commas that should have a space after them.

[EDIT: after my space after comma remark i added the following]

- In `bern_seq` you do not need the square brackets in the list
  comprehension. It is a bit shorter to return the tuple immediately
  without the variable `bseq` like you did in function `bin_words`:

  ```
  return tuple(int(np.random.rand(1) < freq1s) for _ in range(length))
  ```
- Docstrings lines should be limited to 72 characters according to
  PEP8.
- In `check_dict` there should be no spaces around the = for de the
  default parameter value.
- In `check_dict` the string "km is ..." is a comment an should use "#
  " at the beginning of each line instead of surrounding triple quotes.
  (happens two times more in this function)
- The `__name__ == "__main__"` part could use blank lines whenever you 
  use a
  bare `print` statement. The calculating and printing could be more
  separated. Although this has little to do with PEP8 and more with 
  personal taste . I took the liberty to rewrite the main part to:

  ```
  max_key_len = 8
  dict_len_max = 2**max_key_len
  dat_len = data_size(dict_len_max)

  print "Let's make a dictionary with ", max_key_len, 
  print "-bit keys out of a random bitstring."
  print "How long should that bitstring be if we want max length but "
  print "certainty of 8-bit keys?"
  print "It should be ", dat_len, " bits long"
  print

  freq1s = np.random.rand(1)
  bitstring = bern_seq(dat_len,freq1s)

  print "Let's make it ", round(freq1s*100,1), "percent 1's"
  print "The first 30 digits are ", bitstring[:30]
  print

  library = LZ78Dict(bitstring)
  dict1 = library.encode_dict
  coded1 = library.encode(bitstring)

  print "This dictionary has ", len(dict1), "key-value pairs"
  print "It was able to encode the bitstring in ", len(coded1), " bits"
  print "The first 30 of those are ", coded1[:30]
  print

  decoded1 = library.decode(coded1)
  matches = decoded1 == bitstring

  print "Now let's decode that"
  print "The first 30 digits of the decoded bitstring are ", decoded1[:30]
  print "It is",
  print ["false", "true"][matches],
  print "that these code operations are able to "
  print "reverse each other flawlessly."
  ```

Comment: Such as, defining the inputs for functions, giving inputs to functions, and printing things?

Comment: @Post169, yes in all those cases, I tried to look up the rule in PEP8, but to my suprise it was not there, [see also this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31741418/pep8-space-after-a-comma).

Comment: Clearly the 72 characters includes indentations, as that part of PEP 8 is about making everything fit on the page.

Comment: I like the idea to separate parts of the script with blank lines, and the idea to group `print`s together, but between the fact that I want the lines I wrote to remain continuous and that I would like to make this compatible with Python 3, I think I'll adjust your suggestion to fit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346230/wrap-long-lines-in-python#3346295). (I appreciate the rest of your points, too. I wish I could click the check on both answers; I'll deliberate on the question for a little while longer.)